# Match string exactly from list of strings

Tags: python

I have a list of a device's port numbers that I want to match against but I don't want duplicates and it needs to match exactly.

Here's an example of the list:

```
port_list = ['port 1.1', 'port 1.2', 'port 1.3', 'port 1.4', 'port 1.5', 
'port 1.6', 'port 1.7', 'port 1.8', 'port 1.9', 'port 1.10','port 1.11', 
'port 1.12', 'port 1.13', 'port 1.14', 'port 1.15', 'port 1.16', 'port 1.17', 
'port 1.18', 'port 1.19', 'port 1.20', 'port 1.21',  'port 1.22','port 1.23', 
'port 1.24']
```

I found this code that works except for when I have say port 1.23 it matches the correct port but also 1.2 or for port 1.16 I also get a match for port 1.1.

```
matches = {x for x in port_list if x in output}
```

This is the output I pull the port from in an earlier part of the script

```
LAB-5150-MES1.NMD*> config search string "virtual-switch ethernet add"
virtual-switch ethernet add vs 022NMD001111BL port 1.20 vlan 4
virtual-switch ethernet add vs 022NMD002222BL port 1.21 vlan 20
virtual-switch ethernet add vs 022NMD003333BL port 1.23 vlan 452
```

Then here's what I'm trying to accomplish with pulling the port from above but it's matching on that extra port.

```
LAB-5150-MES1.NMD*> lldp set port 1.2 mode tx-rx notification off
LAB-5150-MES1.NMD*> lldp set port 1.20 mode tx-rx notification off
LAB-5150-MES1.NMD*> lldp set port 1.23 mode tx-rx notification off
LAB-5150-MES1.NMD*> lldp set port 1.21 mode tx-rx notification off
```

Comment: If the order does not matter too much, why not use a `set` to remove any duplicate?

Comment: Can you show us what `output` looks like? That way, we can determine why `'port 1.23'` matches with `'port 1.2'`

Comment: What is the value of `output`? (Give an example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`output` must be a string, right? That's why `'port 1.1' in output` is `True` when it's actually `'port 1.16'`. So you could simply divide it in a list and check if the number of the port is in it:

```py
matches = {x for x in port_list if x.split()[1] in output.split()}
```

No need to use regex ;)

Edit: `x.split()` divides the string in a list. Each division is on a space. So the result of it is `['port', '1.16'`]. We use the `[1]` index notation to specify the object on index 1 (python index start on 0) - `'1.16'`. That way, we're checking if the number is on the list of words on `output`.

Comment: so no need to test for `port`. Shortcut, but that'd work yes (best answer so far if you ask me and coming from a newbie it's nice)

Comment: the alternative (testing `port` as well) is tedious. I'd code that only if necessary. Doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: This worked! What does the [1] do though? Tried looking up some info on split but didn't see what [ ] mean.

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
matches = {x for x in port_list if x == output}
```

Comment: output seems to be a list, so that would not work as expected.

Comment: If output is a list, then he wouldn't be getting partial matches like he is.

Comment: With `output="1.2"`, this won't match anything.

Comment: That gives me the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

With the `in` operator you're using substring match, which is why when `output` contains `port 1.23`, it also matches `port 1.2`. In this case you should use regex to make sure that the match occurs only on word boundaries.

```
import re
matches = re.findall('\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(port_list), output)
```

Comment: why is this downvoted? is this wrong? maybe overcomplex, but it seems that it would work. note that I would have used `\b(%s)\b` it's simpler.

Comment: It isn't wrong, but I submitted my answer before the OP provided a sample `output`. At the time using regex to test for word boundaries seemed to be the safest approach. Now that the OP has provided a sample `output`, it's apparent that splitting by spaces is enough to ensure word boundaries, and therefore regex is no longer necessary.

Comment: I prefer not to capture groups unless I actually need certain portions of the string captured, so I use `(?:)` when possible.

Comment: it's no longer necessary except if the pattern must be `ports <something>` not just `<something>` so it's not wrong.